# How to perform a multi-conditional replace in dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset `data.csv` with around 180 variables (words) and 3000 samples (cases), and it looks like this (excerpt):

[image]

I am running `decorana` and plotting a cluster using `kmeans` and `fviz_cluster`:

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv")

DCA <- decorana (veg = log1p (df))

species.scores <- as.data.frame(scores(DCA, "species"))

geom.text.size = 1
theme.size = (14/5) * geom.text.size

set.seed(123)
km.res <- kmeans(species.scores, 4, nstart = 25)
fviz_cluster(km.res, geom = "text", data = species.scores, labelsize = 4)
```

This results in a satisfying cluster graph:

[image: clusters]

I wonder if it would be possible to layer the samples on top of this variable cluster? This will then help to indicate which samples are positioned in which cluster.

Any suggestions on how to achieve something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution, where `Calculate` is determined in the first `mutate` (therefore, outside `if_else`), which can correspond to a very complicated calculation, as you declare you are needing:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 5, 5)
Period <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
Value <- c(10,12,11,4,6)
df <- data.frame(ID, Period, Value)

df %>% 
  mutate(Calculate = Period * Value) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Calculate = if_else(row_number() == n() & Value > 10, 0, Calculate)) %>% 
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>      ID Period Value Calculate
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1      1    10        10
#> 2     1      2    12        24
#> 3     1      3    11         0
#> 4     5      1     4         4
#> 5     5      2     6        12
```

Comment: You got to post this answer before I did, but this is what I was thinking the OP was looking for as well.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to convert values to 0, can multiply with a logical vector so that `FALSE` -> `0` will return 0 and other values (`TRUE` -> `1`) return the original vector (assuming it is numeric)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Calculate = Period * Value) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Calculate = Calculate * !(row_number() == n() & Value > 10)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
     ID Period Value Calculate
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1      1    10        10
2     1      2    12        24
3     1      3    11         0
4     5      1     4         4
5     5      2     6        12
```